# Flutter run Error: No such file or directory

Tags: flutter, android-emulator

When I try to run my app. It shows me this error

```
Using hardware rendering with device AOSP on IA Emulator. If you notice graphics artifacts, consider enabling software rendering with   
"--enable-software-rendering".
Launching lib\main.dart on AOSP on IA Emulator in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                                  
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                        14,5s
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...                 26ms
Error: ADB exited with exit code 1
Performing Streamed Install

adb: failed to open C:\Users\...\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk:
No such file or directory
Error launching application on AOSP on IA Emulator.
```

I try it also with a physical device but I get still the same error.
I have tried many things. 
Wipe Data
Cool boot
Create new Emulator
But non of them worked for me.

Flutter doctor:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.1052], locale de-DE)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.1)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio
[√] VS Code (version 1.58.0)
[√] Connected device (3 available)

• No issues found!
```

I am happy for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to enable software rendering?

```
flutter run --enable-software-rendering
```

Answer (score 1):

Honestly if I were you, I'd just re-make a new app with `flutter create ...`
and then transfer all of the files from your old proj. - I know it's a pain to redo the pubspec.yalm but it's what I would do

Comment: This is a new Project

Comment: :0 Oh my, then I'm not really sure what to do 

Comment: I don't know what happened but I turned on my PC again and tried and know it works fine. But I don't change anything. (And yes I restarted my PC before that too) It seems to be magic. Nevertheless thank you for your help

Comment: Now I have the same problem again. I am frustrated. Please send me help 

Answer (score 0):

found a fix, simply move the file(app.so) from
`\build\windows\runner\Debug\app.so`;
to build\windows\runner\Debug\data\app.so
in most case you have to locate the app.so, i cannot define the structure of your project, but once you find the app.so file simply  move it into the `\build\windows\runner\debug\data` folder